# Excel VBA referencing string in Formula Array

Tags: arrays, string, vba, excel

Need help inserting string into formula array to bypass the 255 character limit.

```
Sub FindCAHS()

Dim HS As Range
Dim refworkbook As Variant
Dim ref1 As Workbook
Dim ref2 As Worksheet
Dim ref3 As String
Dim lastRow As Long


    refworkbook = Application.GetOpenFilename(".xlsx Files (*.xlsx), *.xlsx", 1, "Select the HS Reference xlsx")
    If refworkbook = False Then Exit Sub

    Set HS = Range("J2")
    Set ref1 = Workbooks.Open(refworkbook)
    Set ref2 = ref1.Worksheets.Item(2)

    lastRow = Sheet1.Range("D" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

        For j = 2 To lastRow
            If IsEmpty(Cells(j, 10).Value) = True Then
                 ref3 = "'" & ref1.Path & Application.PathSeparator & _
                 "[" & ref1.Name & "]" & ref2.Name & "'"
                HS.Offset(j - 2, 0).FormulaArray = _
                "=vlookup($F$" & j & "&$G$" & j & "&$H$" & j & ",Choose({1,2},""" & ref3 & """!$C:$C&ref3!$D:$D&""" & ref3 & """!$E:$E,""" & ref3 & """!$F2:$F5000),2,0)"
                Else: Exit Sub
            End If
        Next

    ref1.Close False
End Sub
```

I've tried double-quotes ("" & ref3 & "") and double-double-quotes ("""" & ref3 & """") and I keep getting an application-defined or object-defined error. I feel like this is an easy fix, but I can't seem to figure it out. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Just checking quickly, it may be that on the line `if IsEmpty(Cells(j, 10).Value.....` your reference to Cells(...) is not qualified, you should perhaps have `Sheet1.Cells(..)`

Comment: Just another note, you don't need to check `IsEmpty(..) = True` because IsEmpty() is already True or False, just test `If IsEmpty(...) Then ...`

Comment: My first comment also applies to `Rows.Count` a few lines above.

Comment: Apart from the use of a range name shown in Chris Meurer's answer, it's possible to use the `Range.Replace` method as well.  (I.e. insert a short formula first and then `Replace` parts of it with longer bits.)  Do a google search of `site:stackoverflow.com excel-vba formula array 255 characters`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't get around a [property's character limit](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/range-formulaarray-property-excel) by setting the string in VBA instead of through the UI.

If the length of your string is truly beyond 255-characters, it will continue to fail. As an alternative, you may control the length of the formula better if you use the Names manager to define a [named range pointing to your external workbook](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/create-an-external-reference-link-to-a-cell-range-in-another-workbook-c98d1803-dd75-4668-ac6a-d7cca2a9b95f), and reference that range in your formula. Ie:

```
ActiveWorkbook.Names.Add Name:="MyRange", RefersTo:=Rng1
```

I also agree with JohnRC's comments above - be precise and qualify your references to aid in debugging.